# Cannot establish connection using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I saw similar examples already but none of them had a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to connect to a database to get the data.

When loading the page I get the error:`"The underlying provider failed on Open."`

I browsed through some examples here, but could not find a solution.

I have created a connection in my `Web.config`:
`<add name="EmployeeContext"   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Sample; integrated security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

I have a context file:

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to connect and get the data in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
    Employee employee = employeeContext.Employee.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);

    return View(employee);
}
```

But when I'm getting the data, I have the error when loading  the page:
`"The underlying provider failed on Open."`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC exists 2 web.config files. One is on View folder and the other one in on the project folder. Make sure that your connection string is not set on the web.config from View folder.

Comment: I'm using project's file

Comment: Try to change  Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0 with Data Source=.

Comment: Just did: Data Source=Server_Name\SQLEXPRESS